# SUPEE 6788 AND Admin Routing Compatibility

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I've installed SUPEE 6788 and from default, admin routing compatibility is "Enabled", all extensions work fine. However, when I "Disable" it, extension no longer work, and I have to modify them.

**Question:** Considering I already installed the patch, is it OK to leave routing compatibility as "Enabled" considering you have a strong password ?

Answer (score 2):

With routing compatibility enabled, Magento is allowing the 3rd party modules to use their deprecated method of creating admin backend routes.

That is the meaning of Admin Routing Compatibility, it's kind of like the compatibility mode in Internet Explorer. The page breaks because it runs afoul of some display issue, so make Internet Explorer act like an old version that will display it. Same goes for Magento in compatibility mode, act like the old, insecure unpatched version and allow the module to work.

Which leads to the cure, all modules that fail to appear when the "Admin Routing Compatibility mode is shut off are using the old insecure routing and will need to be upgraded. Contact your module developer and get updates or use the [SUPEE-6788 Tool](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox) elsewhere to find the suggested fix for modules you created and test them.

Magento and strong passwords is still insecure as it doesn't have any method to stop repetitive login retry attacks. Lock down access to an IP whitelist and get an administrative protection module that allows a maximum number of login retries and then locks out access for exceeding that.

The description of the issue as follows means you need to get the modules fixed and get compatibility mode disabled as soon as possible.

> **Attacker can force showing admin panel login page regardless of admin
>   panel URL** by calling a module directly. It makes it easier to try
>   automated password attacks and exposes admin URL on the page.

Comment: What a well written answer. Paradox Labs deserve an award for the SUPEE-6788 Tool, what a headache saver that's proved to be.